# MediaWiki $wgRawHtml enabled and googlemap <iframe> work but embedding webpage doesn't

Tags: html, iframe, mediawiki

We are building a MediaWiki to deliver content for a conference.  There are only a few committee editors so we set $wgRawHtml=true.  This enabled us to put iframe tags between html /html tags to properly display googlemaps so they work as expected there.  However, we would like to include something like:

```
<html>
<iframe width="100%" height="600" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" src="http://oursite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=92&Itemid=84">
</iframe>
</html>
```

to display any of several hundred pages (by changing Itemid value) which contain the formatted text Php output already residing in our Joomla-based site. When I try this (or any other src) I see the frame in MediaWiki, but no content.  Is there a way to make this work?

I suspect that there's a permissions or extension problem somewhere.  I have access control groups, but they all function as expected (readonly folks, writers, users).  My localsettings.php only has

```
$wgDBname = blah;
$wgSitename = blah;
$wgLocalInterwiki - $wgSitename;
# Skin/logo settings
#$wgDefaultSkin      = 'blah';
#$wgLogo             = "$wgStylePath/common/images/wiki.png";
# Authentication configuration
#$wgLDAPUseLocal          = true;
#$wgLDAPDisableAutoCreate = array( "cauth" => true );
$wgEnableUploads    = true;

$wgGalleryOptions  =  array  (
         'imagesPerRow'  =>  4,  // Default number of images per-row in the gallery
         'imageWidth'  =>  120,  // Width of the cells containing images in galleries (in "px")
         'imageHeight'  =>  120,  // Height of the cells containing images in galleries (in "px")
         'captionLength'  =>  20,  // Length of caption to truncate (in characters)
         'showBytes'  =>  true,  // Show the filesize in bytes in categories
         'mode'  =>  'traditional',  // One of "traditional", "nolines", "packed", "packed-hover", "packed-overlay"
);
###########
# and because I only have a few editors I have included html
###########
$wgRawHtml = true; 

$configdate = gmdate( 'YmdHis', @filemtime( __FILE__ ) );
$wgCacheEpoch = max( $wgCacheEpoch, $configdate );
# Whitelisted pages
#$wgWhitelistRead = array( "Main Page", "Special:Userlogin" );
```

Comment: What is the html shown as a result?

Comment: The iframe appears, but there is no content at all

Comment: "No content" you mean blank block with width 100% and height 600px? What if you open iframe src? Content is displayed?

Comment: Correct.  A blank block of the right dimensions appears, but no content is displayed regardless of the src address.  If I go to the src address in a browser it is, of course, displayed.

Comment: Then your src page have javascript that blocks iframe embedding.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, nope, that's not it.  Tried using several sources with no scripting (e.g. http://stevemiller.net/puretext/).  I suspect there's got to be a permissions problem or missing basic extension.

Comment: Aha! While trying different browsers I noticed that an old IE warned me about mixed secure/insecure elements on the page. Since the wiki is on a university site it is https:// which seems to be stopping the iframes from loading the src!  Voila!  If I include a secure source it loads.  So now I either have to use secure source or unsecure the wiki serving.  Thanks ancap!

Answer (score 0):

Aha! While trying different browsers I noticed that an old IE warned me about mixed secure/insecure elements on the page. Since the wiki is on a university site it is https:// which seems to be stopping the iframes from loading the src! Voila! If I include a secure source it loads. So now I either have to use secure source or unsecure the wiki serving. Thanks ancap!